# Display in Sheet1 newest entries from Sheet2 to Sheetn in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which has an arbitrary number of sheets. From Sheet2 to Sheetn the structure is the same:

```
|   A  |  B   |   C   |   D  | 
------------------------------
| Date | Name | Value | Type |
| Date | Name | Value | Type |
```

However, these rows are not sorted by the date, so the 1st row of each sheet is not guaranteed to be the newest date.

The first sheet has one row for each sheet and it should be updated to include the most recent entry in each sheet.

For example, if we have 4 Sheets, then Sheet 1 will have 4-1=3 rows which will be: the row with the newest date of Sheet 2, the row with the newest date of Sheet 3, and the row with the newest date on Sheet 4.

A file equals a thousand words, so you can [download the excel file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhbwhbhxuh2u8p1/Book1.xls?dl=1) and see what I need.

Comment: Sounds simple - use MAX on date column over range of rows per sheet.

Comment: How do I do that? If I type '=MAX()' on A1 cell of Sheet1 and put the Date column of Sheet 2, I get '=MAX(RBC!C:C)' which only returns the newest date. However I want the whole row that has the newest date, not only the date itself.

Comment: Then you are in the realms of scripting or macros at that point. Try Googling Excel Object Model. Then get your heard around ranges etc

Comment: Thank you. I actually managed to do it myself ^^

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured out a solution. I'm guessing it's significantly far from the best one, but since I'm by no means an excel person, the fact that it works is enough for me.

For other non-excel people who just need to achieve this without learning excel, here's how I did it:

```
=INDEX(MySheetName!$A$2:$G$10000,(MATCH(MAX(MySheetName!$C:$C),MySheetName!$C:$C,0)-1),COLUMNS(MySheetName!$A$1:A1))
```

Replace "MySheetName" on its 4 occurrences to the actual Sheet name of each of your excel's sheets.
Replace Columns 'A to G' on the INDEX to the columns you want to retrieve.
Replace Column C:C on the MATCH to the column you want used to retrieve the row number using its MAX()
Remember to span the formula to multiple columns, as many as the maximum columns that the sheet you reference has.

What I'd like to improve now is to make it able to span multiple rows as well, which for me it would mean that it would automatically reference all the columns of the next excel sheet. For now, one needs to manually replace "MySheetName".
The "10000" also looks really bad, but I don't know how to many sure that it will get the Max() over all rows. I'll never fill more than 100 rows on each sheet, so 10000 seems safe.